# Directly fetching a list from a column's data with MySQL

Tags: php, sql, mysql, list, transpose

Let us suppose I have to deal with lots of grandmothers that have lots of cats. I have a table granny_cat :

```
granny_id | kitty_name
--------------------
1           Kizzy
1           Jimmy
1           Katty
2           Georges
2           Albert
3           Panther
```

and I want to retrieve a list of granny 1 cat's, i.e. to get something like (with php syntax)

```
array("Kizzy","Jimmy","Katty")
```

However, the query

```
SELECT kitty_name WHERE granny_id = 1
```

returns something like

```
array
(
   array('kitty_name' => "Kizzy"),
   array('kitty_name' => "Jimmy"),
   array('kitty_name' => "Katty")
)
```

what is quite logical, as I can fetch two, or more fields with a similar query. I can obviously map this array to get what I want, however, I wonder whether there is a (simple) way to get it directly from mysql, or not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(kitty_name) 
FROM    mytable
WHERE   granny_id = 1
```

will give you the comma-delimited list which you can `explode` into an array.

`MySQL` does not support native array datatype. In `PostgreSQL` you would be able to do the following:

```
SELECT  ARRAY
        (
        SELECT  kitty_name
        FROM    mytable
        WHERE   granny_id = 1
        ) AS kitties
```

, which would give you a native `PHP` array.

Comment: Thanks, even if I can't use the PostgreSQL solution, my curiosity is satisfied. The comma-separated list however is dangerous, what if some cat is named "Oh, you're a cute kitty !!" ?

Comment: @hlanak, good follow-up question.  You'll need to handle your own field delimiters (which you can specify in GROUP_CONCAT via SEPARATOR) and escaping.  You might HEX() encode the fields before catenation, for example.

Answer (score 0):

A wrapper library will typically handle this, e.g. [ADODb](http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm) has the [GetCol()](http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm#getcol) method:

```
$names=$db->GetCol('SELECT kitty_name WHERE granny_id = 1');
```

Comment: Well, yes, but I wanted to know if I can get it directly from mysql.